# Set a variable into JavaScript function with content that's loaded before on another part of page with JSON feed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could I append the code that's created by JSON from another part of a HTML page in to a new variable in a function?

I know that, with jQuery, I can grab HTML from another part of the page and put it wherever I want, but is there any possibility to do this with a new variable into a javascript function?

```
<script>
 function new22(json) {
    var htmlcode ='';
    document.write( htmlcode );
    for ( var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++ ) {
        for ( var j = 0; j < json.feed.entry[ i ].link.length; j++ ) {
            if ( json.feed.entry[ i ].link[ j ].rel == 'alternate' ) {
                var postUrl = json.feed.entry[ i ].link[ j ].href;
                break;
            }
        }
        var postTitle = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
        var postThumbSize = 600;
        var postThumb = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
        postThumb = postThumb.replace( '/s72-c/', '/s' + postThumbSize + '/' );
        var postCategory = json.feed.entry[i].category[0].term;
        var item = '[locationData("'+postTitle+'", "'+postUrl+'", "", "", "name", "", "+38099231212", "5", "27"), 40.72956781, -73.99726866, 0, markerIcon],';
        htmlcode += '';
        document.write(item);
    }
    }
</script>
```

that is called with following

```
<script> document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/summary/-/shop?max results=4&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in script&amp;callback=new22\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);</script>
```

and i want the previous result to put it into another JavaScript function in a new variable

var locations=[*here*];

Comment: Basically yes. If jQuery can do it then JavaScript can do it for sure.

Comment: How? Do you have any code, how to set new variable?

Comment: Well since you wrote that you know how to do it in jQuery, why not just do the same without? Unless I missunderstood your statment.

Comment: Append in jquery is a code that help to set an element from another part of page wherever you want but this could work into javascript?  For example....                                                                                                                  
                  $('div.breadcrumb-text.text-center h2').append($("h1.post-title.entry-title"));

Comment: document.querySelector('div.breadcrumb-text.text-center h2').appendChild(document.querySelector('h1.post-title.entry-title'));

Comment: there is a way to check what javascript did when i run the code? I've made the test and nothing it happens. Is there any tool?

Comment: Well, I am not sure what you are trying to do. For example you keep writing `htmlcode` which is just set to empty string repeatedly. All you are currently outputting is some '[locationData(..'. You are neither passing any variable nor trying to append any elements in your example. Also you can append a script tag in the header by `createElement()`. If you provide a working example with input, code, output & expected output, people would or could actually consider helping you out.

Comment: Lain do you have an email to sent you a personal message. My own email is triantafillopoulos.loukas@gmail.com. If you want sent me an email to reply on this. Thank you